How to find the vertices of a 3D Shape Calc III (e.g. hyperboloid of one sheet, elliptical paraboloid, etc..)
I can find out the shape and put it in standard form. I just don't know what to do when it asks about the vertices. Sorry I'm new and it won't let me attach images yet.
Example Question of the problems I'm stuck on
Image of my work

Both images of your question should be typed out using MathJax, click here for a quick tutorial.

@VincentBatens I understand, are you able to help me out by any chance with my question?

I don't see any reference to vertices in your image of the question.  Your working out looks fine.  What additional salient features are worth mentioning?  There is an axis of symmetry.  I might mention the local max and min of the y coordinate (the x and z coordinates do not have local extrema)

whoops it's literally just setting two of the variables equal to zero and solving for the other one.
